# How to parse a text file that is formatted like a gradebook?

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a text file that has data formatted as follows:

```
Name|Test1|Test2|Test3|Test4|Test5|Test6|Test7|Test8|Test9|Test10   
John Smith|82|89|90|78|89|96|75|88|90|96
Jane Doe|90|92|93|90|89|84|97|91|87|91
Joseph Cruz|68|74|78|81|79|86|80|81|82|87
```

My goal is to be able to get each student's average test score, as well as the average score per test (column) and the average score overall. I am having trouble "separating" the first columns (the names of the students) from their test scores. Is there a way to ignore or skip the first column? Also, what is the best way to store those test scores so that I will be able to do those calculations I mentioned?

I have successfully read the contents of the file by using the below method:

```
in.useDelimiter("\\|");
for(int i = 0; in.hasNextLine(); i++){
    System.out.println(in.next());}
```

Comment: Just call `in.nextLine()` before you enter the loop, that way you fully consume the first line.

Comment: yes, I forgot to include that bit, but that's exactly how I did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You can achieve what you want by fully consuming the first line before you enter your loop, just call

```
in.nextLine();
```

before and the first line is consumed.

---

### Splitting

However, I would approach this differently, parsing line by line and then splitting on `|`, that way it is easier to work with the data given per line.

```
in.nextLine();
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String[] data = line.split("\\|");

    String name = data[0];
    int[] testResults = new int[data.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
        testResults[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[i + 1]);
    }

    ...
}
```

---

### Proper OOP

Ideally you would add some OOP to that, create a class `Student` with fields like

```
public class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final int[] testResults;

    // constructor, getter, ...
}
```

and then give it a `parseLine` method like:

```
public static Student parseLine(String line) {
    String[] data = line.split("\\|");

    String name = data[0];
    int[] testResults = new int[data.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < testResults.length; i++) {
        testResults[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[i + 1]);
    }

    return new Student(name, testResults);
}
```

Then your parsing simplifies heavily to just:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
in.nextLine();
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    students.add(Student.parseLine(in.nextLine());
}
```

---

### Streams and NIO

Or if you like streams, just read the file using NIO:

```
List<Student> students = Files.lines(Path.of("myFile.txt"))
    .skip(1)
    .map(Student::parseLine)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

very clear, compact and readable.

---

### Average score

> My goal is to be able to get each student's average test score, as well as the average score per test (column) and the average score overall.

With the proper OOP structure, as shown, this is fairly simple. First, a students average score, just add a method to the `Student` class:

```
public double getAverageScore() {
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int testResult : testResults) {
        total += testResult;
    }
    return total / testResults.length;
}
```

Alternative stream solution:

```
return IntStream.of(testResults).average().orElseThrow();
```

Next, the average score per column:

```
public static double averageTestScore(List<Student> students, int testId) {
    double total = 0.0;
    for (Student student : students) {
        total += student.getTestScores()[testId];
    }
    return total / students.size();
}
```

And the stream solution:

```
 return students.stream()
       .mapToInt(student -> student.getTestScores[testId])
       .average().orElseThrow();
```

And finally the average score overall, which can be computed by taking the average of each students average score:

```
public static double averageTestScore(List<Student> students) {
    double total = 0.0;
    for (Student student : students) {
        total += student.getAverageScore();
    }
    return total / students.size();
}
```

and the stream variant:

```
return students.stream()
    .mapToDouble(Student::getAverageScore)
    .average().orElseThrow();
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but is there a way to calculate the column totals (Test1 total, Test2 total, etc.) without using OOP?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. Programming is about structuring your code nicely such that you can do the task easily and create readable and maintainable code. Stuffing everything into a single method without using classes and methods doesnt really achieve that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and I really appreciate your help. But I was just wondering if there's another way since I am not quite at your level yet.

Comment: Im just not really sure what exactly you mean by *another way*, i.e. what kind of response or approach you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to store the data you read in a `Map`. Where each student's name is the "key" and the scores are stored in an `List<Integer>` which you put as the value in you map.

Like so:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> scores = new HashMap<>();

List<Integer> studentScores = new ArrayList<>();
// then you read the scores one by one and add them 
studentScores.add(82);
studentScores.add(89);
....
// when you are finished with the student you add him to the map
scores.put("John Smith", studentScores);

// in the end, when you need the values (for your calculation for example) you can get them like this:

scores.get("John Smith").get(0)   // which will be the 1st value from John's list => 82
```

Now to the actual reading: I don't think you need a delimiter, just read the whole line and `split` it afterwards:

```
scanner.nextLine();                      // I almost forgot: this reads and forgets the very first line of your file

while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
     String line = scanner.nextLine();   // this is a whole line like "John Smith|82|89|....."
     // now you need to split it
     String[] columns = line.split("|"); // straight forward way to get an array that looks like this: ["John Smith", "82", "89", ...]

    
     String studentName = columns[0];   // first we get the name
     List<Integer> studentScores = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i=1;i<columns; i++){       // now we get the scores
        studentScores.add(Integer.valueOf(columns[i])); // will read the score at index i, cast it to an Integer and add it to the score list
     }
     // finally you put everything in your map
     scores.put(studentName, studentScores);
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that "Map"s can only keep unique keys, so if you have two students with the same name, the second student will override the scores from the first student... For your to decide. A more proper solution would be the OOP way with an Object for each Student as @Zabuzard suggested

Comment: **Edit** I just realised that you also wanted to know how to read/skip the first line, so I added that part. If you are not sure about the content of the file you can also read all lines (including the first one) in the while loop and analyse the lines before treating them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `in.nextLine()`:

```
//to skip first line with headers
in.nextLine();

while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String studentLine = in.nextLine();
        int firstColumnEnd = studentLine.indexOf("|");

        String name = studentLine.substring(0, firstColumnEnd - 1);
        String[] tests = studentLine.substring(firstColumnEnd + 1).split("\\|");
}
```

Comment: This doesnt skip the very first line, which is OPs main issue.

Comment: @Zabuzard What is OP?

Comment: Original Poster, the author of the question, i.e. `NRMA`.